# How to move timeline bar in music player below?

Tags: colors, timeline

I want to move the status bar in music player in my [site](http://deil.cz/), to be the same like this [site](http://ektor.cz/). So need to move below for 100px I suppose, but I can't find the right class, to change myself. I think that class is this:

```
.player-box .jp-seek-bar { 
  padding-bottom:100px; --> But manipulation this value don't change nothing!
}
```

Also, how to change status bar to be the same color like demo site I provided?

Comment: I checked, and when edit this CSS:

`.audio-holder.player-timeline .player-box .jp-progress{
 margin-top:85px;
}`

all is ok, but when insert into Custom CSS, nothing is changed.. What is problem?

Answer (score 0):

### 7 Steps for Troubleshooting or "Why Isn't My CSS Showing?!"

1. **Clear the cache:** CMS's like Drupal very helpfully stash your CSS so it's zippy when you reload the page...and using the old, unchanged CSS.
2. **Check the URL:** Make sure you're looking at the right environment, which comes up more often than you might think. Use the inspector to see if your changes are getting consumed.
3. **C is for Cascading:** The last definition wins, so ensure you're not overriding yourself later in the document. The order of the individual stylesheets matters too. If a plugin's stylesheet is loaded after your custom styles, it wins the throwdown.
4. **Preflight it:** Try it in the browser inspector dev tools before putting into your custom styles.
5. **Details matter:** Check your spelling, match your brackets. Are all your semicolons in place? Run it through a validator: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/
6. **Oh javascript:** If you're overriding an inline style set by javascript you'll either need to track down the javascript setting it or use the !important stick in your CSS.
7. **Caniuse:** If your style definition is something a little edgy, it's possible the browser doesn't support that CSS property. Check http://caniuse.com/ before you drive yourself crazy trying to get IE to behave.