# How to show black logo in mini fixed menu?

Tags: css, image

I have one issue with showing a logo in a small fixed menu, when the user scrolls down.

The logo that is shown in the main menu is OK, but the logo that is shown in the small fixed menu, when the user scrolls down, is shown in white on a white background, so it is not visible at all.

How can I show a black logo on a white background? Image of the issue below:

[image: issue problem]

My site is [deil.cz](http://deil.cz/)

classic-menu.php code:

```
<?php

$post_id = get_the_ID();

if(is_home() && get_option('page_for_posts') != '') {

    $post_id = get_option('page_for_posts');

}else if(is_front_page() && get_option('page_on_front') != '') {

    $post_id = get_option('page_on_front');

}else if(function_exists('is_shop') && is_shop() && get_option('woocommerce_shop_page_id') != '') {

    $post_id = get_option('woocommerce_shop_page_id');

}elseif($wp_query && !empty($wp_query->queried_object) && !empty($wp_query->queried_object->ID)) {

    $post_id = $wp_query->queried_object->ID;
}


$menu_width = get_iron_option('classic_menu_width');
$menu_align = get_iron_option('classic_menu_align');
$menu_position = get_iron_option('classic_menu_position');
$menu_effect = get_iron_option('classic_menu_effect');
$menu_logo_align = get_iron_option('classic_menu_logo_align');

$menu_is_over = get_field('classic_menu_over_content', $post_id);
if(!empty($menu_is_over)) {
    if($menu_position == 'absolute absolute_before') {
        $menu_position = 'absolute';
    }else{
        $menu_position = 'fixed';
    }
}

$container_classes = array();
$container_classes[] = 'classic-menu';
$container_classes[] = $menu_effect;
$container_classes[] = $menu_position;


$menu_classes = array();
$menu_classes[] = 'menu-level-0';
$menu_classes[] = $menu_align;
$menu_classes[] = $menu_width;

if($menu_logo_align == 'pull-top')
    $menu_classes[] = 'logo-pull-top';

$hotlinks_align = 'pull-right';


?>

<div class="<?php echo implode(" ", $container_classes); ?>"
data-site_url="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/') ); ?>"
data-site_name="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo('name') ); ?>"
data-logo="<?php echo esc_url( get_iron_option('header_logo') ); ?>"
data-logo_page="<?php echo esc_url( get_field('classic_menu_logo', $post_id)   ); ?>"
data-retina_logo="<?php echo esc_url( get_iron_option('retina_header_logo') ); ?>"
data-logo_mini="<?php echo esc_url(   get_iron_option('classic_menu_header_logo_mini') ); ?>"
data-logo_align="<?php echo esc_attr($menu_logo_align); ?>">
<?php
echo wp_nav_menu( array(
    'container' => false,
    'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
    'menu_class' => implode(" ", $menu_classes),
    'echo' => false,
    'fallback_cb' => '__return_false'
));
?>

<?php
$top_menu_enabled = (bool)get_iron_option('header_top_menu_enabled');
$menu_items = get_iron_option('header_top_menu');
$menu_icon_toggle = (int)get_iron_option('header_menu_toggle_enabled');
?>
<?php if($top_menu_enabled && !empty($menu_items)): ?>

<!-- social-networks -->
<ul class="classic-menu-hot-links <?php echo (!empty($_GET["mpos"]) ?   esc_attr($_GET["mpos"]) : get_iron_option('menu_position')); ?>">
    <?php foreach($menu_items as $item): ?>
    <?php
    if(!empty($item["menu_page_external_url"])) {
        $url = $item["menu_page_external_url"];
    }else{
        $url = get_permalink($item["menu_page_url"]);
    }
    $target = $item["menu_page_url_target"];
    $hide_page_name = !empty($item["menu_hide_page_title"]) ? (bool)$item["menu_hide_page_title"] : false;
    ?>
        <li class="hotlink <?php echo $hotlinks_align;?>">
        <a target="<?php echo esc_attr($target);?>" href="<?php echo        esc_url($url); ?>">

            <?php if(!empty($item["menu_page_icon"])): ?>
            <i class="fa fa-<?php echo esc_attr($item["menu_page_icon"]); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($item["menu_page_name"]); ?>"></i>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if(!$hide_page_name): ?>
                <?php echo esc_html($item["menu_page_name"]); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if(function_exists('is_shop')): ?>

                <?php global $woocommerce; ?>

                <?php if (!empty($item["menu_page_url"]) && (get_option('woocommerce_cart_page_id') == $item["menu_page_url"]) && $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count > 0): ?>

                    <span>( <?php echo esc_html($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> )</span>

                <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

header.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="<?php echo   (is_admin_bar_showing())? 'wp-admin-bar':''?> ">
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height,   initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<?php 
if ( ! function_exists( '_wp_render_title_tag' ) ) :
    function theme_slug_render_title() {
?>
<title><?php wp_title('-', true, 'right'); ?></title>
<?php
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_slug_render_title' );
endif;?>
<?php wp_head(); ?> 
</head>
<body <?php body_class("layout-wide"); ?>    onload="jQuery('header').animate({'opacity': 1})">
<?php 
$facebook_appid = get_iron_option('facebook_appid');
if(!empty($facebook_appid)) { ?>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '<?php echo esc_html($facebook_appid);?>',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.1'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<?php } ?>

<div id="overlay"></div>

<?php 
$fixed_header = get_iron_option('enable_fixed_header');
$menu_type = get_iron_option('menu_type');
$menu_position = get_iron_option('classic_menu_position');
$menu_is_over = get_field('classic_menu_over_content', get_the_ID());

if(!empty($menu_is_over)) {
    if($menu_position == 'absolute absolute_before') {
        $menu_position = 'absolute';
    }else{
        $menu_position = 'fixed';
    }   
}

?>

<?php if($menu_type == 'push-menu'): ?>
    <?php get_template_part('parts/push', 'menu'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php if($menu_type == 'classic-menu' && $menu_position != 'absolute' &&    $menu_position != 'absolute absolute_before'): ?>

    <?php get_template_part('parts/classic', 'menu'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(($menu_type == 'push-menu' && empty($fixed_header)) || ($menu_type    == 'classic-menu' && ($menu_position == 'fixed' || $menu_position ==   'fixed_before'))) : ?>    
<div id="pusher" class="menu-type-<?php echo esc_attr($menu_type);?>">
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($menu_type == 'push-menu'): ?>
<header class="opacityzero">
    <div class="menu-toggle">
        <?php echo      wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_request(get_template_directory_uri().'/images/        svg/menu_icon.svg')); ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_template_part('parts/top-menu'); ?>

    <?php if( get_iron_option('header_logo') !== ''): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/'));?>" class="site-logo">
      <img id="menu-trigger" class="logo-desktop regular" src="<?php echo   esc_url( get_iron_option('header_logo') ); ?>" <?php echo  (get_iron_option('retina_header_logo'))? 'data-at2x="' . esc_url(  get_iron_option('retina_header_logo')) .'"':''?> alt="<?php echo esc_attr(  get_bloginfo('name') ); ?>">
    </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</header>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php if(($menu_type == 'push-menu' && !empty($fixed_header)) || ($menu_type   == 'classic-menu' && ($menu_position != 'fixed' || $menu_position ==  'fixed_before'))) : ?> 
<div id="pusher" class="menu-type-<?php echo esc_attr($menu_type);?>">
<?php endif; ?>


    <?php if($menu_type == 'classic-menu' && ($menu_position == 'absolute'   || $menu_position == 'absolute absolute_before') ): ?>

        <?php get_template_part('parts/classic', 'menu'); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <div id="wrapper">
```

Comment: We need to see some code to be able to help. Please follow the guidelines for creating a minimal, complete, and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try filter:**

When you trigger your menu's background from black to white, apply a filter to the logo:

```
.classic-menu-logo {filter: invert(.8) }
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Note: according to http://caniuse.com/#search=filter, this is not supported by IE.

Comment: that not make any change.. I added in custom CSS, but nothing changed.

Comment: Hi i tryed to add this code into CSS Editor, and changes applyed, but when add that CSS into custom CSS in site, changes are not visible..

http://i.imgur.com/JFTC83Z.png?1

Comment: Is it getting overridden? Check your order and ensure nothing below it is overriding your specification; clear your cache; if it's getting overridden by javascript functionality, you may need to break out the "! important" stick.

Comment: This is working  sollution:

`.classic-menu > ul > li.logo a img {
      display: block;
      max-height:30px;
      max-width: 100%;
      -webkit-filter: invert(.8);
  filter: invert(.8);
}
.classic-menu.fixed.mini.mini-active > ul > li.logo img, .classic-    menu.fixed.mini.mini-fullwidth-active > ul > li.logo img {
      max-height: 30px;
      max-width: auto;
      -webkit-filter: invert(.8);
      filter: invert(.8);
}`

Comment: can you help me with this issue?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978221/how-to-move-timeline-bar-in-music-player-bellow

Answer (score 0):

1) Make a second black logo and upload it somewhere to your server

2) Remove the logo image from the navigation

3) Add this code to your style.css:

```
.classic-menu > ul > li.logo a {
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/White2.png);
    background-size: contain;
}
.classic-menu.mini > ul > li.logo a {
    background-image: url(/path/to/your/black.png);
}
```

/path/to/your/ is of course only an example, you must adjust it to where you have uploaded the dark logo.

Comment: That now make any change..

I added black logo: 

/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/black.png

in css, but not make any changes. Still white logo is showing.

Comment: I see that the image is still in the logo

Comment: I think it's impossible for me to give advice if I don't work on the theme. Did you try the other answer in this question?